# React native bundle changes not taken in account

Tags: javascript, bundle, react-native

I had a Component with this method :

```
onRegionChangeComplete = (region) => {
  var mapHeight = windowHeight - 124;

  var centerCircleLatitude = region.latitude + (mapHeight -  windowWidth  - (topSize * 2)) * (region.latitudeDelta / (2 * mapHeight));
  var centerCircleLongitude = region.longitude;

  RestaurantsActions.setRegion(radius, region.longitude, region.latitude, region.longitudeDelta, region.latitudeDelta, centerCircleLongitude, centerCircleLatitude, windowWidth, mapHeight);
  this.setState({data: RestaurantsStore.filteredRestaurants()});
  this.setState({isChanging : false});
  this.setState({index : 0});
  this.refs.carousel.goToPage(this.state.index, 'annotationPress');
}
```

I changed the code above deleting the two last lines to :

```
onRegionChangeComplete = (region) => {
  var mapHeight = windowHeight - 124;

  var centerCircleLatitude = region.latitude + (mapHeight -  windowWidth  - (topSize * 2)) * (region.latitudeDelta / (2 * mapHeight));
  var centerCircleLongitude = region.longitude;

  RestaurantsActions.setRegion(radius, region.longitude, region.latitude, region.longitudeDelta, region.latitudeDelta, centerCircleLongitude, centerCircleLatitude, windowWidth, mapHeight);
  this.setState({data: RestaurantsStore.filteredRestaurants()});
  this.setState({isChanging : false});
}
```

When running react-native bundle, I check the output file and it still has those two lines I deleted. Is there a cache or something remaining ?

My bundle command line :

```
react-native bundle --dev true --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --verbose --platform ios
```

I'm using react-native 0.16.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found out, the bundle used a cache version of the packager. I removed it by doing :

```
rm -f $TMPDIR/react-packager*
```

Then I re-runnned the bundle command and it worked fine.