# React-Native bundle does not match current code base

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I made some changes to my react-native iphone app that work fine when the code is coming from the local server. When I switch the code location to the bundle, however, I'm seeing an old version of the app. I even tried trashing main.jsbundle and rebuilding it with `react-native bundle`, but the problem persists.

Comment: This did the trick for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611918/react-native-bundle-changes-not-taken-in-account